# SmartFox server

Tags: iphone, smartfoxserver

Im currently working on an iphone app project. The app is based on a simple chat function between 2 or more people who have registered to the app. Iv outsourced the project. The developers working on the project would like to use Smartfox servers for the Client and Server side communication. They said its easier to manage and setup and is more efficient.
However Im not sure what the disadvantages are of using the Smartfox framework and whether I should just ask them to develop/code the client and server communication rather than using this framework.

Please let me have your suggestions on this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual response is: it depends on your budget, your time and needs.

If you just want to make a chat without advanced features, you may make it yourself. I tell "may" because if already made solutions exist why reinvented the wheel?! (except for the price).

However if you envisage to have a lot of users, some cool features or other you should consider a third solution (like Smartfoxserver, Electroserver, or other). They provide robust solutions with a good documentation. Moreover they offered a tons of features, new one appear regularly, there are updated, etc. Below a small non-exhaustive list of pros and cons of using Smartfox rather than a homemade solution, in my opinion:

Advantages compared with a homemade solution:

- Gain time
- Robust solution
- Performance
- Multi-platform
- Scalability (in time and concurrent users)
- Deployment
- Network engine fully functional (TCP/UDP, HTTP Tunneling, etc.)
- Low learning curve
- Low maintenance costs
- Tons of features (in your case Buddy Lists, Moderation, Filters, etc.)
- etc.

Disadvantages:

- Price (for > 100 CCU) (it takes a long time to develop a homemade solution though + maintenance cost)
- Many features that you will not use

I hope it'll help you in your reflection.